# close session in wordpress

Tags: php, session, wordpress

I put this code for true random posts in all pages, but the session still alive after closing browser.

functions.php

```
session_start();

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {

    $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
    if (empty($seed)) {
      $seed = rand();
      $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
    }

    $orderby_statement = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

How can restart session in wordpress? If the same user reload index.php i want post are random, not the same of last session.

Answer (score 1):

Just always make a random one:

```
$_SESSION['seed'] = rand() ;
```

Or check for last visited page:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['last_page']) && $_SESSION['last_page'] === $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']){
  $_SESSION['seed'] = rand();
} else {
  $_SESSION['last_page'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `unset();` to delete session vars. on every page reload like  `unset($_SESSION['seed']);` or destroy all session with the login information with `session_destroy();`

The other solution you can always make a random seed with `$_SESSION['seed']=rand();`